# IF SUM Equation between two columns

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, sum, multiple-columns

I am inputting a lot of data into excel that is inputted such as `A, B, A, C, B, B, C, A` in one column and then numbers in the following column, such as `3, 4, 2, 3, 3, 5, 0, 1`. With each number/letter having its own cell, each letter cell having a number next to it on the cell in the next column.

I’m trying to form an equation where in a separate cell it will sum up all the numbers next to the A cells, another with the B cells, and so on and so forth. There is no order to the letters and I can’t group them because of the type of data and can’t seem to figure it out. Any ideas?

Comment: With Office 365 this is rather easy with SORT/UNIQUE and SUMIF

Comment: Sounds like you want SUMIF.

Comment: You can google how to use SUMIF or SUMIFS. Alternatively, you can try using a pivot table, which can also be googled. :)